# one-one relation sqlalchemy flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement 1-1 relation for User and Profile Tabels like below.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now())

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {self.email}>'.format(self=self)


class CustomerProfile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer_profiles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'), unique=True)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref("CustomerProfile", uselist=False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CustomerProfile {self.full_name}>'.format(self=self)
```

My question is:

Is this the correct representation of 1-1 mapping? Cause when I try to reverse engineer the database with MySQL Workbench, it does show me one to many mapping
If this is the correct representation, then inserting a duplicate row is being allowed **unless I give unique=True in user_id**. I would have expected that since I told MySql about the mapping, it should not allow duplicate row...Is that not true?

after having a look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

I changed my code to below:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now())

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    customer_profiles = db.relationship('CustomerProfile', uselist=False, back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {self.email}>'.format(self=self)


class CustomerProfile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer_profiles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='customer_profiles')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CustomerProfile {self.full_name}>'.format(self=self)
```

but still, I am able to insert a duplicate row into profiles....

Since I am mapping it at the DB level, I am assuming that DB will stop me from inserting a duplicate row even though I do not give unique=True.. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: you need to add a foreign key in `User` to `customer_profile_id`